# Using Facebook SDK to Upload Screenshot in Unity

Tags: android, facebook, url, unity-game-engine

I'm am trying to use Facebook SDK to Upload Screenshots to Facebook using `FB.Feed()` instead of `FB.API()` so that users can write a message to their post. I was able to get this to work on Unity Editor but when I try it on my Android, I get:

> "This dialog has been passed a bad parameter.
>
> API Error Code: 100 
>   API Error Description: Invalid parameter
>   Error Message: picture URL is not properly formatted"

And here is the code I wrote:

```
var width = Screen.width;
var height = Screen.height;
var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
// Read screen contents into the texture
tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
tex.Apply();
byte[] screenshot = tex.EncodeToPNG();
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Screenshot.png", screenshot);

//Application.CaptureScreenshot(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Screenshot.png");
Debug.Log(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Screenshot.png");
Debug.Log("Does File Exist? " + File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Screenshot.png"));
Debug.Log("File://" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/Screenshot.png");
FB.Feed(
    picture: "File://" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/Screenshot.png"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload image to facebook using `FB.Feed()`, `picture` parametr must be url in web.

To upload image you may use `FB.API("me/photos")` method

```
private void TakeScreenshot()
{
    var width = Screen.width;
    var height = Screen.height;
    var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    // Read screen contents into the texture
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    byte[] screenshot = tex.EncodeToPNG();

    WWWForm wwwForm = new WWWForm();
    wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, "screenshot.png");

    FB.API("me/photos", HttpMethod.POST, CallBack, wwwForm);
}
```